# can i search an array of functions and run the searched function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am trying to write an application that searches an array of functions and does the function that was found.

```
var search = 'test';
var valid_input_array = [
     function test(){console.log('test');},
     function abc(){console.log('abc');}
];

for (i = 0; i < valid_input_array.length; i++) {

  if (valid_input_array[i].name === search) {
    valid_input_array.search;
  }

}
```

It does find the function but it doesn't run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call found function

```js
var search = 'test';
var valid_input_array = [function test(){console.log('test');},function abc(){console.log('abc');}];

for(i = 0; i < valid_input_array.length; i++){
   if(valid_input_array[i].name === search){
       valid_input_array[i]()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Array#find()`

```js
var search = 'test';
var valid_input_array = [
      function test(){console.log('test');},
      function abc(){console.log('abc');}
];


var funcWanted = valid_input_array.find(function(fn) {
  return fn.name === search
})

// only call it if find doesn't return false
funcWanted && funcWanted()
```